Index notation for the generalized form of the velocity field dependance on shear and rotation
Good day guys, I was studying fluid dynamics and came across the following equations (shown in the image):
When we have both shear and and rotation, they each contribute to the change in velocity field by adding their contributions. The shear components of the strain-rate tensor, and the vector components of the rotation/angular velocity vector. The LHS of the equations looks good to me, but fail to see why using index notation it would be written as the RHS, which uses two indices for the rotation vector, is it a mistake?

